# Convert varchar dd/mm/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy datetime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert a date in a `varchar` column in the `dd/mm/yyyy` format into the datetime `dd/mm/yyyy` format, so then I can run date range queries on the data.

So far I have the following which is not working

```
CONVERT(varchar, CAST(date_started AS datetime), 103)
```

I have also tried

```
convert(date_started as datetime, 103)
```

I need to make sure the output is as `dd/mm/yyyy` as we're in the UK and not the `mm/dd/yyyy` format

Comment: Y U NO STORE DATE AS DATETIME?

Comment: i didnt, im working with a system which isnt mine

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you are after this:

```
CONVERT(datetime, date_as_string, 103)
```

Notice, that `datetime` hasn't any format. You think about its presentation. To get the data of `datetime` in an appropriate format you can use

```
CONVERT(varchar, date_as_datetime, 103)
```

Comment: Thats what i had before, sorry. my mistake

That also converts, but when i do a > '01/06/2013' on the date im seeing dates in january.

Comment: > CONVERT(datetime, '01/06/2013', 103) - then everything is in datetime and the comparison is done on datetime datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
CONVERT(varchar(15), date_started, 103)
```

Comment: Didnt work im afraid, it converted but when i added the > '01/06/2013' part to it, i was seeing dates back in 2011

Comment: @Stew what do you mean with the "> '01/06/2013'"-part you did not mention anything about that in your OP what did you do with it?

Comment: SELECT     date_started
FROM         staff
WHERE      (CONVERT(datetime, date_started, 103) > '01/06/2013')

When i do this im seeing dates in January, not after 1st June 2013

Comment: it is automatically 01 is taking January month so that problem arise you convert 06/01/2013 is working

Answer (score 0):

I think that more accurate is this syntax:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103)
```

I add SELECT and GETDATE() for instant testing purposes :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a format mm/dd/yyyy, then use 101 instead of 103:
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [MyDate], 101)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, convert(date, '27-09-2013', 103), 103)
```