# MS SQL DATABASE SEARCH BETWEEN 2 Dates and Times

Tags: sql-server

I have got 2 columns in my table called 'Date' and 'time'.I want to search records from certain date and time TO certain date and time. How can i do this?

Datatype  nvarchar for both columns
Date Format  dd/mm/yy
Time format  HH:mm:ss

I am also passing these parameters:
fromdate
todate
fromtime
totime

Comment: Are the data types also `Date` and `Time`?

Comment: PLEASE post the data type of your columns!  If they are VARCHAR or similar, also post the format in which they are stored - e.g., are we looking at yyyy-mm-dd, mm/dd/yyyy, etc.

Comment: no date and time columns are nvarchar(50)

Comment: And what is the format of the time column?  This kind of information is great to include as an edit to your original post (click the word 'edit' below your question) rather than as a comment, since it would be useful for everyone viewing the question.

Comment: +1 for responsiveness and editing your question to include requested information!  For future questions, information like that should be included in the original post. There are [lots of places](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to read about how to ask a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the fun of it (and mostly because I really, really dislike trying to do something like this against the wrong data types), you could use a CAST() function like this (assuming that, whatever your data type, it's possible to convert it to a DATETIME).

**Edited to reflect data type / format mentioned as a comment**

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE (MyDate VARCHAR(50), MyTime VARCHAR(50))

INSERT INTO @MyTable (MyDate, MyTime) VALUES ('21/08/2014', '07:29:01')
INSERT INTO @MyTable (MyDate, MyTime) VALUES ('12/08/2014', '09:29:02')
INSERT INTO @MyTable (MyDate, MyTime) VALUES ('21/08/2014', '16:29:04')


SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, MyDate,103) + CAST(MyTime AS DATETIME) FROM @MyTable
WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, MyDate,103) + CAST(MyTime AS DATETIME) BETWEEN '8/21/2014' AND GETDATE()
```

**Edit again**

The extra code up there is just to provide a demo of the theory in action, since I don't have access to your source data - applying it to your table would just use the last part, like:

```
   SELECT *
   FROM WhateverYourTableIsNamed
   WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, [Date],103) + CAST([Time] AS DATETIME) BETWEEN '8/21/2014 00:00:00.000' AND '8/21/2014 09:58:32.000'
```

Comment: when comparing , does this date format needs to be mm/dd/yyyy?

Comment: The 103 in `CONVERT(DATETIME,MyDate,103)` is meant to take the dd/mm/yyyy format into account - see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315204/convert-varchar-dd-mm-yyyy-to-dd-mm-yyyy-datetime). This puts the column into SQL Server's DATETIME data type, which makes things like `BETWEEN` lots easier.

Answer (score 0):

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fe88f/2/0):

```
SELECT m.*
FROM MyTable m
WHERE CONVERT(Datetime, m.Date + ' ' + m.time, 120) 
      BETWEEN '2003/01/01 07:00:00' AND '2003/12/31 23:00:00';
```

Comment: but my date and time column are of nvarchar(50) data type..is this gonna work?

Comment: what about date format as my date format which is being compared against the table is dd/mm/yy?

Comment: SELECT * 
FROM MyTable m
WHERE (CONVERT(DATE, m.Date, 103) BETWEEN fromdate AND todate)
AND (CONVERT(TIME, m.time) BETWEEN fromtime AND totime)

Comment: the above code is only comparing time and not the date range :(

Comment: This answer is wrong.  It will only give records from 7AM to 11PM from 1/1 to 12/31.  It will exclude records from 11PM to 7AM in that same date span.  The OP is looking for all records from 7AM on 1/1 to 11PM on 12/31.

Comment: **@Johnny Bones** and **@Bilal**, I fixed my answer and provided a working SQL Fiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

1 tip. i would change the column names because it will cause another error as Date is probably a built in keyword.

also try this..

```
SELECT * 
FROM xxx 
WHERE dates >= '20121026' 
AND dates <  '20121028'    --- one day after 
                         --- it is converted to '2012-10-28 00:00:00.000'
```

;